# Can batch files not process large numbers?

Tags: batch-file

For the sake of my own amusement, I decided to try writing a batch file to calculate [Hailstone Sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hailstone_sequence).  However, I ran into a small problem with some large-ish numbers.

First, the code:

```
:START
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET /P InputVar="Input Number: "
ECHO.
ECHO %InputVar%
SET ItCount=0

:COLLATZ
SET /A ItCount=%ItCount%+1
SET /A Odd=%InputVar%%%2
IF %Odd% EQU 1 (
    SET /A OutputNum=%InputVar%*3+1
) ELSE (
    SET /A OutputNum=%InputVar%/2
)
ECHO %OutputNum%
IF %OutputNum% LSS 1 (
    GOTO ERROR
) ELSE (
    GOTO RECYCLE
)

:ERROR
ECHO.
ECHO ERROR!
GOTO END

:RECYCLE
IF %OutputNum% EQU 1 (
    GOTO FINISH
) ELSE ( 
    SET InputVar=%OutputNum%
    GOTO COLLATZ
)

:FINISH
ECHO.
ECHO Completed in %ItCount% iterations.

:END
ENDLOCAL
PAUSE
```

This works for several numbers I've tested.  However, when I got around to testing a number that I new would take hundreds of iterations to complete, the system started returning *negative* outputs.  Interestingly, the negative outputs eventually resolved to zero.  However, this behavior of the script is not at all expected or intended.

After adding in the error handling, this is the output I get for `8388607`.

[image]

According to [Google](https://encrypted.google.com/search?&q=725594111*3%2b1), the next number should have been `2176782334`.

Is this a natural limitation of the command processor's ability to handle large numbers?  Similar operations run fine in Excel - there, I was able to determine the number should have resolved to 1 in 473 iterations.

I'm running Windows 7 SP1 x64.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

2176782334 is larger than an 32bit integer can hold. (2^31 - 1 = 2,147,483,647). What you are experiencing is integer overflow, (causing negative values).

Most modern languages have a datatype `long` that will allow you to hold integers in the range of -2^64  to 2^64 -1. There are even data types to allow infinite precision integers, like Java's `BigInteger`.

Comment: Why am I limited to 32 bits on a 64-bit system?  Is CMD.exe still a 32-bit application?

Comment: I don't think it supports a long datatype, probably because it's not built for programs like this. It doesn't have anything to do with the OS. Is there a reason you don't want to do this in another language?

Comment: Pretty much just because I don't know any real languages.  Learning one or two of those is still on my to-do list.

Comment: it's not related to 32 or 64-bit cmd.exe. The type `int` is still 32 bits in most modern systems

Answer (score 2):

The largest possible integer in a batch file is most likely 2,147,483,647 (the maximum value of a 32 bit signed integer).

Comment: remove the words "most likely" and you have the correct answer :-)

Comment: I couldn't find a reference to back up my assertion.