# Batch file multiply positive variables return a negative number

Tags: batch-file, multiplication, area

I've been working on a Batch polygon area calculator and I got a problem.
I need to multiply 2 variables, but sometimes it return a negative number if the two positive variables are large.

Here's an example: `999999*999999` returns `-729379967`.

Code goes below:

```bat
REM Calc square area
:PolySqu
Cls
Echo                                        Polygon Area Calculator 
For /L %%P In (1,1,57) Do Echo.
Set /P "InputPolygonCalSqu=Enter one of the line's length in cm :"


Set /A SquArea=InputPolygonCalSqu * InputPolygonCalSqu


Cls
Echo                                        Polygon Area Calculator
For /L %%P In (1,1,57) Do Echo.
Echo The area of this square is %SquArea% cm2.
Pause
Goto :PolygonCal
```

It seemed the command

```
Set /A SquArea="InputPolygonCalSqu * InputPolygonCalSqu
```

doesn't calculate properly.

Comment: This is one of only two situations where I will ever recommend using PowerShell on a question with the [batch-file] tag.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38579524/how-do-i-use-basic-batch-math-commands-to-come-up-with-decimal-answers/38579735#38579735 for a way of using double precision floating maths.

Comment: @Noodles Thank you for solution, I've already point out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others already pointed out, a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) natively supports 32-bit signed integer arithmetics only.

The following code constitutes a work-around for multiplying non-negative numbers greater than the limit of 2<sup>32</sup> − 1 = 2147483647, using pure [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) commands (let us call it `multiply.bat`):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define arguments here:
set "NUM1=%~1"
set "NUM2=%~2"
set "NUM3=%~3"
set "NUM4=%~4"
if defined NUM1 set "NUM1=%NUM1:"=""%
if defined NUM2 set "NUM2=%NUM2:"=""%
if defined NUM3 set "NUM3=%NUM3:"=%
call :VAL_ARGS NUM1 NUM2 NUM4 || exit /B 1

rem // Define constants here:
set /A "DIG=4" & set "PAD="
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%J in (1,1,%DIG%) do set "PAD=!PAD!0"
endlocal & set "PAD=%PAD%"

rem // Determine string lengths:
call :STR_LEN LEN1 NUM1
call :STR_LEN LEN2 NUM2
set /A "LEN1=(LEN1-1)/DIG*DIG"
set /A "LEN2=(LEN2-1)/DIG*DIG"
set /A "LIM=LEN1+LEN2+DIG"
for /L %%I in (0,%DIG%,%LIM%) do set /A "RES[%%I]=0"

rem // Perform block-wise multiplication:
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%J in (0,%DIG%,%LEN2%) do (
    for /L %%I in (0,%DIG%,%LEN1%) do (
        set /A "IDX=%%I+%%J"
        if %%I EQU 0 (set "AUX1=-%DIG%") else (
            set /A "AUX1=%DIG%+%%I" & set "AUX1=-!AUX1!,-%%I"
        )
        if %%J EQU 0 (set "AUX2=-%DIG%") else (
            set /A "AUX2=%DIG%+%%J" & set "AUX2=-!AUX2!,-%%J"
        )
        for /F "tokens=1,2" %%M in ("!AUX1! !AUX2!") do (
            set "AUX1=!NUM1:~%%M!" & set "AUX2=!NUM2:~%%N!"
        )
        call :NO_LEAD0 AUX1 !AUX1!
        call :NO_LEAD0 AUX2 !AUX2!
        set /A "RES[!IDX!]+=AUX1*AUX2"
        set /A "NXT=IDX+DIG, DIT=DIG*2"
        for /F "tokens=1,2,3" %%M in ("!IDX! !NXT! !DIT!") do (
            set "AUX=!RES[%%M]:~-%%O,-%DIG%!"
            set /A "RES[%%N]+=AUX"
            set "RES[%%M]=!RES[%%M]:~-%DIG%!"
            call :NO_LEAD0 RES[%%M] !RES[%%M]!
        )
    )
)

rem // Build resulting product:
set "RES=" & set "AUX="
for /L %%I in (0,%DIG%,%LIM%) do (
    set /A "RES[%%I]+=AUX"
    set /A "NXT=%%I+DIG"
    for /L %%J in (!NXT!,%DIG%,!NXT!) do (
        set "AUX=!RES[%%I]:~-%%J,-%DIG%!"
    )
    set "RES[%%I]=%PAD%!RES[%%I]!"
    set "RES=!RES[%%I]:~-%DIG%!!RES!"
)
endlocal & set "RES=%RES%"
call :NO_LEAD0 RES %RES%

rem // Return resulting product:
echo(%RES%
if defined NUM3 (
    endlocal
    set "%NUM3%=%RES%"
) else (
    endlocal
)
exit /B


:NO_LEAD0  rtn_var  val_num
rem // Remove leading zeros from a number:
for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%Z in ("%~2") do (
    set "%~1=%%Z" & if not defined %~1 set "%~1=0"
)
exit /B 0


:STR_LEN  rtn_length  ref_string
rem // Retrieve length of string:
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "STR=!%~2!"
if not defined STR (set /A LEN=0) else (set /A LEN=1)
for %%L in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
    if defined STR (
        set "INT=!STR:~%%L!"
        if not "!INT!"=="" set /A LEN+=%%L & set "STR=!INT!"
    )
)
endlocal & set "%~1=%LEN%"
exit /B 0


:VAL_ARGS  ref_arg1  ref_arg2  ref_arg3
rem // Check arguments for validity:
if not defined %~1 >&2 echo ERROR: too few arguments given! & exit /B 1
if not defined %~2 >&2 echo ERROR: too few arguments given! & exit /B 1
if defined %~3 >&2 echo ERROR: too many arguments given! & exit /B 1
(call echo "%%%~1%%" | > nul findstr /R /C:"^\"[0-9][0-9]*\" $") || (
    >&2 echo ERROR: argument 1 is not purely numeric! & exit /B 1
)
(call echo "%%%~2%%" | > nul findstr /R /C:"^\"[0-9][0-9]*\" $") || (
    >&2 echo ERROR: argument 2 is not purely numeric! & exit /B 1
)
exit /B 0
```

To use it provide the two numbers to multiply as command line arguments; for instance:

```
multiply.bat 999999 999999
```

The resulting product is returned on the console:

> ```
> 999998000001
> ```

If you provide a third argument, the product is assigned to a variable with that name; for example:

```
multiply.bat 999999 999999 SquArea
```

This sets variable `SquArea` to the resulting value. The latter is also still returned on the console.
To silently assign the variable without any additional console output, redirect it to the `nul` device:

```
multiply.bat 999999 999999 SquArea > nul
```

Comment: Perhaps you might be interested in [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38579834)...

Answer (score 1):

Batch uses 32bit integers for storing numbers. This gives them a maximum size of 2^31 - 1 = 2,147,483,647.

999,999 * 999,999 = 999,998,000,001 which is larger than 2,147,483,647 therefore it "wraps" and starts from negatives.

This is a limitation of batch although there are some [workarounds](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_math.php).

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful

[Can batch files not process large numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546020/can-batch-files-not-process-large-numbers)

The largest number batch can take is 2^31 - 1 = 2,147,483,647.

So again, it is starting back from negative and giving you that answer..

Answer (score 0):

I noticed using pure batch, it would be somewhat to very difficult to implement operations that support the numbers beyond the 32-bit integer limit. So instead, I limited the numbers, so they won't overflow when multiplied.

```
REM Calc Square Area
:PolySqu
Cls
Echo                       Polygon Area Calculator
For /L %%P In (1,1,57) Do Echo.
Set /P "InputPolygonCalSqu=Enter one of the line's length in cm [Less then 40000] :"
If %InputPolygonCalSqu% GTR 40000 Goto :PolySqu

Set /A SquArea="InputPolygonCalSqu * InputPolygonCalSqu


Cls
Echo                       Polygon Area Calculator
For /L %%P In (1,1,57) Do Echo.
Echo The area of this square is %SquArea% cm2.
Pause
Goto :PolygonCal
```