# How do I use basic batch math commands to come up with decimal answers?

Tags: batch-file, math, decimal

I am making a batch file so that I just tell it what kind of formula I need to use and it tells me what variables I need to input. Right now, I am coding it so that it will find the area of a triangle.

I have written the code so that it asks you the base, height, and the units of the triangle. As you should know, the formula is simply, base x height / 2. So I tested the code to see if it works. But I noticed that when it divides an odd number by 2, it doesn't give a decimal answer. It instead rounds down a number. (Ex. 15/2=7)

Here is my code:

```
    set /p TriangleB=How long is the base of the triangle? (Don't put the unit, just put the number):
    set /p TriangleH=What is the height of the triangle? (Don't put the unit, just put the number):
    set /p TriangleAreaUnit=What unit is the triangle being measured in?:
    set /a TriangleArea=%TriangleB% * %TriangleH% / 2
    echo The area of the triangle is %TriangleArea% %TriangleAreaUnit%.
    pause >nul
    goto :EOF
```

It doesn't give me any error message and everything seems to be running smoothly, I just can't figure out as to why it won't give me a decimal answer.

Comment: Batch math can only handle 32-bit integers. If you need decimals or large numbers, use PowerShell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it like that with a batch file :

```
@echo off
set /p "TriangleB=How long is the base of the triangle ? (Don't put the unit, just put the number): "
set /p "TriangleH=What is the height of the triangle ? (Don't put the unit, just put the number): "
set /p "TriangleAreaUnit=What unit is the triangle being measured in ?: "
Call :makevbs %TriangleB% %TriangleH%
echo The area of the triangle is %TriangleArea% %TriangleAreaUnit%^2.
pause >nul
Exit /b

:makevbs
echo wscript.echo Eval( wscript.Arguments(0^) * wscript.Arguments(1^) / 2^) > "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
for /f %%A in ('cscript /nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" %~1 %~2') do set TriangleArea=%%A
exit /b
```

Answer (score 2):

Batch math can only handle 32-bit integers, but there are ways around this limitation. The easiest way is to use PowerShell and take advantage of `for /f` letting you store the output of commands in variables.

```
@echo off

set /p "TriangleB=How long is the base of the triangle? (Don't put the unit, just put the number): "
set /p "TriangleH=What is the height of the triangle? (Don't put the unit, just put the number): "
set /p "TriangleAreaUnit=What unit is the triangle being measured in?: "

for /f %%A in ('powershell %TriangleB% * %TriangleH% / 2') do set TriangleArea=%%A

echo The area of the triangle is %TriangleArea% %TriangleAreaUnit%.
pause >nul
```

As long as you're using a version of Windows older than XP, this will work.

Comment: I just updated my notepad++ software, and now this won't work. It worked yesterday no problem. Now it just doesn't give me an answer, and when I try to exit the batch file because it won't give me an answer, it takes 10 seconds before the file ends. I tried putting it in notepad and then saving it as a .bat file and I got the same results.

Comment: Text editors have no impact on whether or not basic system utilities like PowerShell are installed. Something else on your system changed, but that's a question for SuperUser, not here.

Answer (score 1):

Use this one line basic script

```
    Execute "Wscript.echo " & wscript.Arguments(0)
```

To use

```
    cscript //nologo script.vbs "2.5*2.5"
```

How to use

```
C:\Users\User>cscript //nologo "C:\Users\User\Desktop\New Text Document.vbs" "2.5*2.5"
6.25
```

The second line is how to use the program you just wrote as a command prompt command. `cscript //nologo "c:\somefolder\script.vbs" "%TriangleB% * %TriangleH% / 2"`. Note the expression must be enclosed with quotes if it contains spaces. To put into a command prompt variable use for command. `for /f "delims=" %%A in ('cscript //nologo c:\somefolder\script.vbs "%TriangleB% * %TriangleH% / 2"') Do Set Result=%%A`

So

```
C:\Users\User>Set TriangleB=5.5

C:\Users\User>Set TriangleH=3.5

C:\Users\User>for /f "delims=" %A in ('cscript //nologo "C:\Users\User\Desktop\New Text Document.vbs" "%TriangleB% * %TriangleH% / 2"') Do Set Result=%A

C:\Users\David Candy>Set Result=9.625
```

Remember in a batch use `%%A` and interactively (ie typing) use `%A`

To do the same thing in an HTA (a web page renamed to .hta which makes it act like a program)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="VBScript">
            Sub Calculate
                Answr.innertext = tb1.value * tb2.value /2
            End Sub
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

<p><INPUT Name=tb1 TYPE=Text Value="Height">
<p><INPUT Name=tb2 TYPE=Text Value="Width">
<p><INPUT NAME="Search" TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Calc" OnClick=Calculate>
<div ID=Answr></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And in vbscript only

```
 Wscript.echo InputBox("Height") * Inputbox("width") /2
```

Comment: So I first put "Execute "Wscript.echo" & wscript.Arguments(0)", then immediately afterwards put "cscript //nologo script.vbs "2.5*2.5*""

Comment: When I tried this, it popped up with an error message saying that those codes were not recognizable commands, and it still made the same mistake of not showing decimals.

Comment: No, the first line is its own separate script that you save as `script.vbs`

Comment: NO. The first one is a one line maths program. Put into a file called something.vbs. The second line is how to use the program you just wrote as a command prompt command. `cscript //nologo "%TriangleB% * %TriangleH% / 2"`. Note the expression must be enclosed with quotes if it contains spaces. To put into a command prompt variable use `for` command. `for /f "delims=" %%A in ('cscript //nologo c:\somefolder\script.vbs "%TriangleB% * %TriangleH% / 2"') Do Set Result=%%A`

Answer (score 0):

For the task at hand you could work around the limitation by some kind of fixed-point arithmetics as in the followinf sample code:

```
set /p TriangleB=How long is the base of the triangle? (Don't put the unit, just put the number):
set /p TriangleH=What is the height of the triangle? (Don't put the unit, just put the number):
set /p TriangleAreaUnit=What unit is the triangle being measured in?:
set /a TriangleArea=%TriangleB% * %TriangleH% * 10 / 2
echo The area of the triangle is %TriangleArea:~,-1%.%TriangleArea:~-1% %TriangleAreaUnit%.
pause >nul
goto :EOF
```

What I am doing here is nothing but multiplying everything with 10, so the division by 2 does no longer procude a fractional part that would be lost; afterwards, the decimal separator is inserted by string manipulation operations.
This works only if the input numbers are integers. Of course you can extend that to more decimal figures; but you need to regard that the interim result does not exceed the signed 32-bit limitation.