# wshShell.AppActivate Doesn't Work When In Case -1 As Part Of wshShell.Popup

Tags: vbscript

I have a VBScript I wrote:

```
Dim wshShell, Result
Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Result = wshShell.Popup("Open With File3?", 15, "Excel Files", &H4 + &H20 + &H100)

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("Z:\File1.xlsm")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("Z:\File2.xlsm")

Select Case Result
    Case 6
        Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("Z:\File3.xlsx")
        WScript.Sleep 1000
        wshShell.AppActivate("File3.xlsx - Excel")
    Case 7
       WScript.Sleep 1000
        wshShell.AppActivate("File2.xlsm - Excel")
    Case -1
        WScript.Sleep 1000
        wshShell.AppActivate("File2.xlsm - Excel")
End Select

objExcel.Application.Visible = True
WScript.Quit
```

When the message box pops up and I click on yes or no, wshShell.AppActivate works perfectly. But when I let it count down and Case -1 kicks in, wshShell.AppActivate does not work at all. All I get is Excel's taskbar icon flashing.

Any help will be appreciated.

.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539(v=vs.85).aspx See #3 on the list in remarks of who is allowed to appactivate.

Comment: You mean "The process received the last input event."? Is there a way around this while using the Case -1? I'm still a little new to VBScript. I fumbled my way this far, but this Case -1 part is starting to frustrate me.

Comment: The rules are at that link.

Comment: I get the rules, but is there any alternative to make "File2.xlsm - Excel" the foreground file when Case -1 is activated?

Comment: By doing one of the things on that list. Or **1.** Put your code in an HTA, then it will be allowed to set other windows the foreground. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38579524/how-do-i-use-basic-batch-math-commands-to-come-up-with-decimal-answers/38579735#38579735 **2.** Try moving all code after the message box and remove all sleeps. A program being started has 2 seconds to make it self the foreground window.